# Ruby warning check without backtrace?

Tags: ruby, warnings

I want to check warning with all ruby files in my project.

```
$ cd my_project
$ ruby -w **/*.rb
 /Users/sane/work/tachiko/pigeon.tachikoma.io/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.9.275/lib/new_relic/agent/sql_sampler.rb:9: warning: loading in progress, circular require considered harmful - /Users/sane/work/tachiko/pigeon.tachikoma.io/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.9.275/lib/new_relic/agent.rb
        from config/application.rb:14:in  `<main>'
        from /Users/sane/.anyenv/envs/rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler.rb:134:in  `require'
        from /Users/sane/.anyenv/envs/rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in  `require'
        from /Users/sane/.anyenv/envs/rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in  `each'
        from /Users/sane/.anyenv/envs/rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in  `block in require'
        from /Users/sane/.anyenv/envs/rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in  `each'
        from /Users/sane/.anyenv/envs/rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in  `block (2 levels) in require'
        from /Users/sane/.anyenv/envs/rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in  `require'
        from /Users/sane/work/tachiko/pigeon.tachikoma.io/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.9.275/lib/newrelic_rpm.rb:25:in  `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/sane/work/tachiko/pigeon.tachikoma.io/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.9.275/lib/newrelic_rpm.rb:25:in  `require'
        from /Users/sane/work/tachiko/pigeon.tachikoma.io/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.9.275/lib/new_relic/control.rb:23:in  `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/sane/work/tachiko/pigeon.tachikoma.io/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.9.275/lib/new_relic/control.rb:23:in  `require'  
        from /Users/sane/work/tachiko/pigeon.tachikoma.io/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.9.275/lib/new_relic/agent.rb:40:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/sane/work/tachiko/pigeon.tachikoma.io/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.9.275/lib/new_relic/agent.rb:69:in  `<module:NewRelic>'
    from /Users/sane/work/tachiko/pigeon.tachikoma.io/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.9.275/lib/new_relic/agent.rb:95:in  `<module:Agent>'
    from /Users/sane/work/tachiko/pigeon.tachikoma.io/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.9.275/lib/new_relic/agent.rb:95:in  `require'
    from /Users/sane/work/tachiko/pigeon.tachikoma.io/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.9.275/lib/new_relic/agent/sql_sampler.rb:10:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/sane/work/tachiko/pigeon.tachikoma.io/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.9.9.275/lib/new_relic/agent/sql_sampler.rb:10:in  `require'
/Users/sane/work/tachiko/pigeon.tachikoma.io/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/safe_yaml-1.0.4/lib/safe_yaml.rb:28: warning: method redefined; discarding old safe_load
/Users/sane/.anyenv/envs/rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:283: warning: previous definition of safe_load was here
(snip)
```

I want to show warning(line1, line20 and line21). I don't want to show backtrace(line2-line19).

1. Is this right way to get warning from my project?
2. How to hide backtrace? Any option? or `ruby -w **/*.rb | grep -v LINE_START_WITH_SPACE` ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this right way to get warning from my project?

I use:

```
ruby -wW2 /path/to/script.rb
```

to get full warnings when I'm checking code.

Ruby's command-line helps says:

```
  -w              turn warnings on for your script
  -W[level=2]     set warning level; 0=silence, 1=medium, 2=verbose
```